# $u_n = 1/n^2$ if $n \in [\![k^2, (k+1)^2]\!] , k \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ and $u_n = 1/([\sqrt{n}]^4+n-[\sqrt{n}]^2)$, does $\sum u_n$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ such that :

$u_n = 1/n^2$ if $n \in [\![k^2, (k+1)^2]\!] , k \in 2\mathbb{N}+1$ and $u_n = 1/([\sqrt{n}]^4+n-[\sqrt{n}]^2)$ if $n \in [\![v^2, (v+1)^2 [\![, v \in 2\mathbb{N}$

Hence we have : $u_1 =1, u_2 = 1/4, u_3 = 1/9, u_4 = 1/16, u_5 =1/17, u_6 = 1/18, ...$

I would like to know if : $\sum u_n$ converge.

What I've note so far is that : 
$u_n$ is strictly decreasing, and has limit $0$.

$\pi^2/6 \leq \sum u_n \leq H_n$, but it's hard for me to really see how to advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want
$u_n 
= 1/([\sqrt{n}]^4+n-[\sqrt{n}]^2)
$

If
$(2k)^2 
\le n
\lt (2k+1)^2
$,
let
$j = n-(2k)^2
$.
Then
$0 \le j 
\le (2k+1)^2-(2k)^2-1
=4k
$
and
$\sqrt{n}
\lt 2k+1
$
so
$k \gt (\sqrt{n}-1)/2
$.

$[\sqrt{n}]^4+n-[\sqrt{n}]^2
=(2k)^4+((2k)^2+j)-(2k)^2
=(2k)^4+j
\gt ((\sqrt{n}-1)/2)^4
\gt n^2/256
$
for
$n \gt 4$.

So the sum of the reciprocals of those $n$
is less than
$256\sum\frac1{n^2}$
which converges.

Answer (score 0):

$[\sqrt n\;]^4+n- [\sqrt n]^2\;\geq\;$ $ [\sqrt n\;]^4+n- (\sqrt n\;)^2=\;$ $\;[\sqrt n\;]^4 \geq\;$ $\;(-1+\sqrt n\;)^4 .$

So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $0<u_n\leq 42/n^2.$